# Break setInterval and variable undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and tried doing this script. Onclick it should grab the price of the item and stop the price dropping. Onclick, it doesn't stop and it doesn't grab the price shown. Please advise.

The price should be:-

Start Price: 100
Lowest Max Price: 90

```js
function updateValue(task) {
  var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value + "00";
  var maxamt = document.getElementById("maxamount").value + "00";
  var amountgrabbed = document.getElementById("revese-amt").value;

  var decimal_places = 2;
  var decimal_factor = decimal_places === 0 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, decimal_places);
  var floored_number = Math.floor(amount) / decimal_factor;
  var floored_number_max = Math.floor(maxamt) / decimal_factor;
  floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(decimal_places);
  floored_number_max = floored_number_max.toFixed(decimal_places);

  if (task == "stop") {
    console.log(amountgrabbed);
    check(refreshid, "stop", amountgrabbed);
  } else {

    var refreshid = setInterval(function() {
      floored_number = floored_number - 1 / 100;
      floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(decimal_places);
      if (floored_number < floored_number_max) {
        check(refreshid, "over");
      } else {
        $('#revese-amt').html(floored_number);
      }

    }, 100);

  }

}

function check(refreshid, status, amt) {

  if (status == "over") {
    clearInterval(refreshid);
    $('#revese-amt').html('Deal Gone!');
  } else if (status == "stop") {
    console.log(amt);
    clearInterval(refreshid);
    alert('Congratulations! You have grabbed the item @ price of RM ' + amt);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input 
     type="text" 
     name="amount" 
     id="amount" 
     value="Start Price" 
     onclick=""/>
<BR>
<BR>
<input 
     type="text" 
     name="maxamount" 
     id="maxamount" 
     value="Lowest Max Price" 
     onblur="updateValue()"
 />
<span id="maxa"></span>
<BR>
<BR>
<div 
     style="width:130px; height:50px; background-color:red;"          
     onclick="updateValue('stop')">
  <center>MYR
    <p id="revese-amt"></p>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: You are only passing two parameters to a function that has 3.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I did pass 3 parameters,

`if (task == "stop") {
    console.log(amountgrabbed);
    check(refreshid, "stop", amountgrabbed);
  } 
`

Comment: @MuthaFury maybe there should be something inside the Start Price input's onclick value?

Comment: @MuthaFury But you didn't here: `check(refreshid, "over");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code about below:

first html `p` tag ,must use `textContent` method to get its text.

```
// change
var amountgrabbed = document.getElementById("revese-amt").value;

// to
var amountgrabbed = document.getElementById("revese-amt").textContent;
```

Comment: Nice! 1 problem solved, there is another. How do I stop my SetInterval?

Comment: or `document.getElementById("revese-amt").innerText;`

Comment: @MuthaFury - declare `var refreshid;` outside `updateValue` function.

Comment: @MuthaFury I just working at it...But I need more console...Could you console.log the `refreshid` that in the `check` method status stop?

Comment: @MuthaFury perhaps like what lgor say,but I think define the var in the if closure is no good but still should work.

Comment: My apology, @lgor is right, every time you `blur` will redefine the `refreshid` to undefined, so must be outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 var amountgrabbed = document.getElementById("revese-amt").value;
```

To

```
 var amountgrabbed = $('#revese-amt').html();
```

So that is matches your assignment of

```
 $('#revese-amt').html(floored_number);
```

And then declare your var refreshid variable in the global space. Giving it access everywhere.

```
  $refreshid = setInterval(function() {
  floored_number = floored_number - 1 / 100;
  floored_number = floored_number.toFixed(decimal_places);
  if (floored_number < floored_number_max) {
    check(refreshid, "over");
  } else {
    $('#revese-amt').html(floored_number);
  }

}, 100);
```